# Find corresponding strings in text

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I need to build an import function where a user can submit a text (a bill) and the function will find the Tax and the amount. So suppose this text is entered (this is actual text we process):

```
DateAmountDescription 
24-01-2016$ 14,99Spotify 
23-01-2016$ 10,50Netflix
23-01-2016$ 5,50Amazon
```

I found the code below to compare the string to our stored keywords:

```
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) 
{
    $pos = strpos($text, $keyword);

    if ($pos === false) {

    } else {
        echo "The string '$keyword' was found in the string.";
        echo " and exists at position $pos<br>";
    }
}
```

This will output: `The string Spotify was found in the string. and exists at position 39.`
Now, what I need to do after this, is that I'd like to also find the amount. So when the function finds Spotify, it also needs to find the corresponding amount of money. Any ideas as to how this can be done?

Comment: you mean in this example spotify would have $ 14,99?

Comment: Yes, Spotify would have 14,99. Netflix 10,50 and Amazon 5,50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex solution:

```
<?php

$string = "DateAmountDescription 
24-01-2016$ 14,99Spotify 
23-01-2016$ 10,50Netflix
23-01-2016$ 5,50Amazon";

$regex = '~(?<amount>[\d,.]+)(?<provider>Spotify|Netflix|Amazon)\s*$~m';
# look for Spotify or Netflix or Amazon at the end of a line (+/- whitespace)
# capture it in the group "provider"
# look for anything that is a digit (\d), dot or comma BEFORE
# capture this to the group "amount"

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo "Found: " . $match["provider"] . " with amount: " . $match["amount"] . "\n";
}
// output
// Found: Spotify with amount: 14,99
// Found: Netflix with amount: 10,50
// Found: Amazon with amount: 5,50

?>
```

To see an online demo, visit [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pE8nK3/1). If you need more providers, present some more expected input strings.